# Two types of asp.net core Web Apps?

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core

I've tried to create a  new ASP.NET Core  web application via Visual Studio and when the new project dialog opened I noticed that it offers two ASP.NET Core templates, one using .NET core and the other the. NET Framework. Why two templates? How can an ASP.NET core application use the regular .NET framework?

Comment: Who two templates? So you can choose which to target. And you can target both by modifying the configuration after you create the application.

Answer (score 8):

ASP.Net Core is a separate thing from .Net Core and .Net Framework. So you are getting the option of running ASP.Net Core on .Net Core or ASP.Net Core on .Net Framework.

You would choose .Net Core if you want to be cross platform and run on Linux or Mac, where as you would choose .Net Framework if you want a full featured more mature framework that only runs on Windows.

See [*Choosing the Right .NET For You on the Server*](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/choosing-the-right-dotnet.html) from [ASP.NET Core Documentation](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/index.html).

Answer (score 5):

In addition to Martin's answer, you can have 2 frameworks in same project (like .NET framework 4.6.1 and .NET core 1.0)

[image]

And during debug you can choose which framework to be used like this-

[image]

To configure both frameworks in your project, you just need to modify project.json like this-

```
   "frameworks": {
      "net461": {

      },
      "netcoreapp1.0": {
         "dependencies": {
            "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
               "type": "platform",
               "version": "1.0.0"
            }
         },
         "imports": [
            "dotnet5.6",
            "portable-net45+win8"
         ]
      }
   }
```