# Difference between asp.net core projects in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core

In Visual Studio we can create three types of project templates:

- ASP.NET Web Application
- ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Core)
- ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Framework)

Based on the question and answer found here:
[Visual Studio 2015 Web Application .NET Core vs .NET Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37627234/visual-studio-2015-web-application-net-core-vs-net-framework)
I understand that when using first option I always will be hosting my app on Windows. The same happens when I pick option 3. For the second option I can host my app on Windows, Mac or Linux. I still don't understand why option 2 and three are both called Core Web Application if for the third option I will be using .net framework. What is the difference between option 1 and 3? Both will use .net framework and both can be hosted only on Windows so why the third option is called Core?

Comment: See if this helps - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38658786/two-types-of-asp-net-core-web-apps/38670523

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's all about the runtime

The first option is ASP.NET (Full, legacy, whatever you want to call it) running on the .net 4.x runtime.

The second option is ASP.NET Core (a reduced set of common functions that work on all platforms) running on .NET Core Runtime.

The third option is ASP.NET Core running on .NET 4.x runtime.  This option is there so that you can write .NET Core applications today, even though you may need functionality that is only available on .net 4.x (ie, you have legacy libraries that have not been ported to .net core, or that cannot run on .net core)

In the third case, you may at a later time convert to a full core application when the dependencies become core, or when the .net core framework matures to include the functionality you need.